# how to create a smart contract that uses ERC20 as way of payment?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, erc-20

im creating a smart contract that will receive and automatically redistribute erc20 tokens!

how can i implement that in solidity?

i've tried a couple of codes examples but nothing have worked so far!

do anyone know how to do it or can give me hints?

maybe add line to receive the gas in ether and then execute the transfer of erc20 tokens?

could really use some help!

Comment: what do u mean by "receive and automatically redistribute erc20 tokens"?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93770/swap-token-for-usdt-create-function-send-1-usdt-and-receive-1-token.